# When you ssh to my machine how do I get your username on your machine?

Tags: ssh, security

Given a corporate environment where we have a `portal` account on many of our servers and we assign keys to the right people who can then do, e.g.

```
$ whoami
minion
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/corporate/portal.key portal@server.corporate.com
Last login: Fri Aug  2 08:43:35 2019 from 1.1.1.1
```

How can we, on `server.corporate.com`, capture the username used on the original machine? In the example above: how do we get "minion"?

And: can we capture it without the minion's knowledge?

Comment: I don't think you can, unless you also have control over the `ssh` command on the host where `minion` is running it.

Comment: Since you don't assign separate accounts, you should assign separate keys. And then [you can tell which key was used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410265/108618).